# what codes can i use to graph a function and to draw an axes

Tags: java, swing

the code below is a bit of what i have so far to help me draw my graph but what i need now is the code that helps me draw a curve and draw the x and y axis.

```
 private void drawCurve(Graphics g, String[] values)
{
    Thread t = new Thread();
    t.start();
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.RED);

    // TODO Draw the curve here

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    // TODO Draw the x and y axis here
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking us to finish your work, instead of asking a question.
However, this documentation might help you a little: [Dwaring Geometric Primitives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html), or this [excelent curves tutorial](http://devmag.org.za/2011/04/05/bzier-curves-a-tutorial/).
Good luck!